# Performance : ArrayBlockingQueue vs manaul implementation with List

Tags: java, concurrency

I need a thread-safe Queue and my question is that are there any performance difference between the queue I implement using List and wait/notify (simplest implementation) and classes such ArrayBlockingQueue and etc.?

Comment: It is impossible to answer your question without knowing how you have implemented it. However the probability that your own implementation of a thread safe queue performs better than the jdk's (and is bug-free) is quite low. And in the end, you can test both and see which performs better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is too vague to be answerable. Here is my advice:

1. If there is a standard class that does the job, use it in preference to rolling out your own.
2. Profile your code on realistic inputs to see where the bottlenecks are.
3. Optimize as appropriate.